# No se muestra campo relacionado en un DataTable usando C#

Tags: asp.net

Supongamos que tengo una clase llamada `Solicitud` y adentro tengo los siguientes atributos:

```
int id
int Nro
string Tipo
IList<Cuentas> cuentas
```

Nota: cuentas esta enlazada por el `id` de solicitud

Lo que quiero hacer es llamar a un campo perteneciente a la clase `Cuenta` y mostrarlo en el `DataTable`:

Algo así:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr role="row">
            <td class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)
            </td>
            <td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nro)
            </td>
            <td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cuentas.Select(x => x.Descripcion)) ????
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cuentas[0].Descripcion) ????
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

La sintaxis que escribí no sé si es la correcta porque en este momento no estoy con el Visual Studio a mano. Lo hice un poco de memoria. Pero lo que quiero reflejar es la idea de lo que quiero hacer.
 Cuando ejecuto el proyecto me sale error de que solo me permite, mostrar campos, propiedades, etc. Creo que tiene que ver con que `Cuentas` es un `List`. Pero cuando yo cargo en un objeto la lista de  solicitudes en el *Controller*, cuando recorro los registros de es a lista. Por cada registro tengo: `id`, `nro`, `tipo`, o la lista de `Cuentas`. Que solamente me trae un solo registro ya que está relacionada con el `id` de Solicitud. Y ahí puedo ver el campo `Descripcion`.

Pero cuando quiero hacer lo mismo en el *View* no me lo reconoce. No me deja el `DataTable`. Solamente acepta atributos simple para mostrar.

La pregunta es, ¿Cómo puedo mostrar en un `DataTable` un campo que se encuentra dentro de un objeto `List` que forma parte del objeto `model` que le pase al *View*?

Answer (score 0):

Partiendo del hecho, que la definición del `Model` es una `List<Solicitudes>`, podemos ajustar el código de esta forma:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr role="row">
            <td class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)
            </td>
            <td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nro)
            </td>
            <td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                foreach (var cuenta in item.cuentas)
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => cuenta.Descripcion)
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Donde ahora, para mostrar todas las cuentas asociadas a cada solicitud debes iterar el elemento `cuentas` del modelo con el siguente segemento de código que de igual forma se encuentra en el ejemplo de arriba:

```
<td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
    foreach (var cuenta in item.cuentas)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => cuenta.Descripcion)
    }
</td>
```